# Question on the proof regarding power series having at least one singularity on the circle of convergence

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

> If $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ has a positive radius of convergence
> $R$, $f(z)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}a_nz^n$ has at least one singularity on
> the circle $\mid z\mid=R$.
>
> proof: If $f$ were regular at every point on the circle on
> convergence, then for each $z$ with $\mid z\mid=R$, there would exist
> some maximal $\epsilon_z$ such that $f$ could be continued to a region
> containing $D(z;\epsilon_z)$. Clearly $\epsilon_z$ would depend
> continuously on $z$ so that, since the circle $\mid z\mid=R$ is
> compact, $\underset{\mid z\mid=R}{min}\epsilon_z=\epsilon>0$
> ...

My question is why would $\epsilon>0$? I also am not sure why $\epsilon_z$ is "clearly" continuous. I only know that if $\epsilon_z$ is continuous on the compact subset, its image will be compact and thus obtain minimum/maximum. I would appreciate any explanation!

Comment: Why bother? Just cover the compact circle with finitely many such disks and take the minimum radius.

Comment: They use a slightly weird "continuous $\;\epsilon\;$ . I'd rather use the fact that the circle $\;|z|=R\;$ is compact. I think that way one gets a much simpler and straightforward argument for a minimal $\;\epsilon>0\;$ . It must be  $\;\epsilon>0\;$ because around each point on the circumference there exists aTaylor series around that point with *positive* convergence radius